# Jquery Next and Prev Button Loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple next and previous function that i wrote but i am having one simple issue. On the last slider on click next, it shows a blank slider then on click next it starts all over as it is supposed to. What am i missing? Below is the jquery code;

```
 $('div.contsliders').each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
   });

$('span.next').click(function(){
    if ($('div.contsliders:visible').next().length != 0)
        $('div.contsliders:visible').next().fadeIn(1000).prev().hide();

    else {
        $('div.contsliders:visible').hide();
        $('div.contsliders:first').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
});

$('span.prev').click(function(){
    if ($('div.contsliders:visible').prev().length != 0)
        $('div.contsliders:visible').prev().fadeIn(1000).next().hide();
    else {
        $('div.contsliders:visible').hide();
        $('div.contsliders:last').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    return false;
});
```

[HERE IS THE JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/joey_ma/fqzrb/3/)

I will really appreciate it mates, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when it checks for the following condition for the div which you think it is the last using `$('div.contsliders:visible').next().length` gives `.contsnextprev` (hence length will still be 1 instead of 0 as assumed) so it shows that one instead of moving to the beginning, which happens when you click on it again. It is because `.contsnextprev` is the div next to the last slide `#five`.

```
if ($('div.contsliders:visible').next().length != 0)
    $('div.contsliders:visible').next().fadeIn(1000).prev().hide();
```

You can change it to:

```
    var $nxt = $('div.contsliders:visible').next('.contsliders');
    if ($nxt.length != 0)
        $nxt.fadeIn(1000).prev().hide();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJa78/)**

Infact you can simplify this to just one handler as well:

```
$('div.contsliders:gt(0)').hide(); //Hide all but the first one

var $allSlides = $('div.contsliders'), 
    traverseDefault = "first", //set the defaults
    actionDefault ="next";

$('span.next, span.prev').click(function(){

    var traverse = traverseDefault,
        action = actionDefault;

    if($(this).is('.prev')){ //if action is prev
        traverse = "last"; //set traverse to last in case nothing is available
        action = "prev"; //set action to prev
    }

    var $curr = $allSlides.filter(':visible'), //get the visible slide
        $nxtTarget =  $curr[action](".contsliders"); //get the next target based on the action.

    $curr.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000).hide(); //hide current one

    if (!$nxtTarget.length){ //if no next
        $nxtTarget = $allSlides[traverse](); //based on traverse pick the next one
    }

    $nxtTarget.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000); //show the target

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xUY84/)**

Comment: Lol smh, thanks man. It totally makes sense. Guess i was too swamped into the code and i over looked at that. Thanks a bunch saved me some time, appreciated.